# ASP.NET URL Re-writing; Is this possible?

Tags: asp.net, automation, url-rewriting

My app is currently written to accept vendor and product information like this.

```
http://www.mydomain.com/foo.aspx?v=1&p=100
```

could this be re-written like this?

```
http://www.mydomain.com/1/100/foo
```

Since the values in the original query string are database IDs, how would I express newly created IDs as segments of the "path" in the re-written version of the URL?  My goal would be to create more of an automated solution that would accomplish this.

EDIT:

The app is written using ASP.NET webforms, .NET 4.0 and IIS 7

Comment: What version of IIS are you using? What version of .NET? The different versions have different capabilities, so an answer depends on this info.

Comment: .NET 4 does have the new routing capabilities for doing stuff like this. I can't give a lot of details, as I haven't had a chance to play around with it yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your own server you might want to look at: http://www.microsoft.com/web/spotlight/urlrewriter/

And otherwise you can have a look at the file BlogEngine.Core\Web\HttpModules\UrlRewrite.cs in the source of http://blogengine.codeplex.com/releases/view/39387 for an example.

The poster below has something if you use .NET 4.0!